# Objective-C Run Time System

Tags: objective-c, runtime

RunTime system is a dynamic library that has enabled dynamic nature of Objective-C. My quesy is that: who runs this Run Time System? Does it runs always along with OS?

Comment: I believe that it is run by Apple and yes, it always runs alongside iOS. It'll only be run in your project if you add the framework from the iOS frameworks list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runtime system sounds like it could be a daemon or something that runs all the time doing runtime-y stuff.

It isn't;  it is simply a set of utility routines that are linked into your application that the compiler generates calls to to implement things like introspection, class realization, and, most commonly used, method calling.

Every Objective-C application will have its own runtime in that every application runs in its own isolated memory space and cannot touch other application's memory.

In other words, the Objective-C runtime is entirely passive.  It does nothing unless some code is executed that calls it (the one exception being when ObjC is running in a GC'd environment as the GC thread(s) will collude with the runtime to clean up memory).

Most high level languages have a runtime system of some kind.   Even C (look up crt0).